# MySQL Stored Procedures, Pandas, and "Use multi=True when executing multiple statements"

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, stored-procedures

***Note - as MaxU suggested below, the problem is specific to  mysql.connector and does not occur if you use pymysql.  Hope this saves someone else some headaches***

Using Python, Pandas, and mySQL and cannot get a stored procedure to return results at all, let alone into a data frame.

I keep receiving errors about multiple queries, but the stored procedures I am running are extremely simple parameter driven queries.

It doesn't matter what stored procedure I use, it is always the same result

In fact, the test procedure below (sp_test) is the following query -

```
select * from users;
```

If I run the same statement with

```
df=pd.read_sql("select * from users", cnx,index_col=None, coerce_float=True)
```

Instead of

```
df=pd.read_sql("call sp_test()", cnx,index_col=None, coerce_float=True)
```

It works fine, even though **sp_test** is **select * from users**

Why do I keep getting multi=true error messages and how do I go about fixing the problem and getting the results of my stored procedure?  I don't understand how a simple select statement would return multiple result sets.

If there is another way to do this, happy to try it.

Following is the simple code I am using

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from pandas import DataFrame
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='jeff', password='password', database='testdatabase', host='xx.xxx.xxx.xx')
df=pd.read_sql("call sp_test()", cnx,index_col=None, coerce_float=True)
```

When I get to pd.read_sql, I get the following error message

```
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py in execute(self, operation, params, multi)
    506             try:
--> 507                 self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
    508             except errors.InterfaceError:

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py in cmd_query(self, query)
725             raise errors.InterfaceError(
--> 726                 'Use cmd_query_iter for statements with multiple queries.')
727 

InterfaceError: Use cmd_query_iter for statements with multiple queries.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\pandas\io\sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1563             else:
-> 1564                 cur.execute(*args)
   1565             return cur

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py in execute(self, operation, params, multi)
    510                     raise errors.InterfaceError(
--> 511                         "Use multi=True when executing multiple statements")
    512                 raise

InterfaceError: Use multi=True when executing multiple statements
```

Comment: have you tried pd.read_sql_query() ?

Comment: yes, same error

Comment: @Jeff, try `pd.read_sql("call sp_test();", ...)` (pay attention at the semicolon). Beside that i would try to run it using different MySQL Python module, for example `pymysql` (this one is used for internal Pandas tests)...

Comment: @Jeff yes if that doesn't work try pd.read_sql("sp_test", cnx)

Comment: Ok, so once I switch to pymysql it works perfectly , but it doesn't work no matter what as long as I am using mysql.connector.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will be of some help.  Using some concept pointers from [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/calling-mysql-stored-procedures-python/), and a little trial / error, I was able to make this work using `mysql.connector` and `pandas`.

```
# CONNECT TO DB AND GET CURSOR OBJECT
conn = <do db connecty stuff>
cur = conn.cursor()

# CALL THE STORED PROCEDURE
cur.callproc('stored_proc_name', ['my', 'usp', 'parameters'])

# EXTRACT RESULTS FROM CURSOR
for i in cur.stored_results(): results = i.fetchall()

# LOAD INTO A DATAFRAME
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['my', 'column', 'headers'])
```

This worked perfectly for me ... I hope it does for you too.