# panda.to_sql to call stored procedure with parameters via mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, read-sql

I've got some **Connection** class which has _**_enter__** and **__exit__** methods to return **mysql.connector.MySQLConnection** instance.

What is required is to run mysql stored procedure and get data as dataframe.
I've tried tons of ways using: ?, %s, :1, %(name)s and passing list, tuple, dict into parameters.

```
with Connection(**self._connection) as conn:
   df = pandas.read_sql("call stored_procedure (?);", conn, params=['test'])
```

I read [Pandas read_sql with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408557/pandas-read-sql-with-parameters), [MySQL Stored Procedures, Pandas, and "Use multi=True when executing multiple statements"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797979/mysql-stored-procedures-pandas-and-use-multi-true-when-executing-multiple-sta) and few others and still can't find a solution as it always failed with **"Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement"** or asks to use Multi = True;

Of course we can read data with cursor, fetch it and pass into DataFrame constructor, but there has to be a way of using pandas.read_sql according to documentation.

Comment: you call your stored proc but you need to actually select the data, where is the select statement?

Comment: you want to say that it's not possible to call SP via read_sql?

Comment: I assume the proc returns a result set. Are there any other statements in the SQL that are returning rows/values

Comment: Re-reading https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.read_sql.html again carefully, I stopped on phrase:
**sql : string SQL query or SQLAlchemy Selectable (select or text object)**
which could mean that you can't call sp in read_sql.

Comment: a stored procedure isn't a table or a sample of data, it's a series of SQL statements that you execute, what you need is the output of the procedure, a dim/fact/stage/temp table of somekind. you need to select that.

Comment: that is exactly what SP is doing - just selecting a row from a table and returning them.

Answer (score 0):

Summary: you can't call SP in that way with parameters
Proof: [Pandas Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.read_sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for odbc / SQL Server. Maybe you can adapt the call for mysql. Basically, just append your parameters:

```
# imports for SQL data part
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

# Get connected

strconnODBC = ("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
            "Server=SERVERNAME;"
            "Database=DATABASENAME;"
            "Trusted_Connection=Yes")       # You may need to enter Login-info

cnn = pyodbc.connect(strconnODBC)


# Call a SQL Server Stored Procedure with Parameters
strMyPara='ShowMeResults'
strSQL="[dbo].[q_Your_SP] "
strSQL= strSQL + " @WhatYouWant='" + strMyPara + "'"

data = pd.read_sql(strSQL , cnn)  
print('Max of ' + strMyPara + ': ' + str(data['Result'].max()))
```